# How to initialize IServiceScopeFactory in test to use Entity Framework core InMemory Database

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mstest

I have HotelRepository class which includes crud functions, i want to test all my repository using EF core in memory database but I am stuck because my repository class constructor takes IServiceScopeFactory

```
Public class HotelRepository
{
    IScopedServiceFactory factory
    public HotelRepository(IScopedServiceFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    public CreateHotel(HotelInformation)
    {
        var context = Create();
        //code to implement save
        context.savechanges();
    }
    
    private HotelDbContext Create()
    {
        return factory.CreateScope().ServiceProvidor.GetRequiredService<Dbcontext>();
    }
}

//using ms tests
public class HotelDb_Tests
{
    public Test_Save_Hotels()
    {
        var options = new DbCOntextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase("TestHotelDb").Options;
        using (var context = new DbContext(Options))
        {
            //How to create instance of HotelRepository which takes IScopedServiceFactory as parameter 
            //Basically want to do the following
            var HotelRepo = new HotelRepo(ScopedServiceFactory);
            HotelRepo.CreateHotel(HotelInformation)
        }
    }
    
}
```

How can i Initialze HotelRepository instance than use inmemory database for testing different function

Comment: You have to provide a test implementation. There are are various libraries like Moq which can help: `var mockSs = new Mock<IServiceScope>(); mockSs.Setup(m => m.GetRequiredService<DbContext>()).Returns(context);` `var mockSsf = new Mock<IScopedServiceFactory>(); mockSsf.Setup(m => m.CreateScope()).Returns(mockSs.Object);` `new HotelRepo(mockSsf.Object)`. That's just an example I'm sure asp.net core specific helpers available

Comment: thanks @AluanHaddad for your input. it  helps to resolve the issue

Comment: I wonder if you could simplify things by injecting a database context factory function instead of a service scope factory. that database factory function could create the scope, abstracting this detail from the Hotel Repository. Of course that might not work for your design but I think it's worth considering. One of the best things about unit testing is that hard to test code often brings up potential changes that could benefit the overall design. So your repo would just depend on a `Func<HotelDbContext>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by simple usage of ServiceCollection:

```cs
// Create service collection
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

// Add DI configurations
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestHotelDb");
    });

// Build ServiceProvider
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();


// Use it in tests per your example

var serviceScopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

var HotelRepo = new HotelRepo(serviceScopeFactory);
HotelRepo.CreateHotel(HotelInformation)
```

Comment: or you may try additional approach: 
**1) Add HotelRepo to DI** to above's configuration: 
`serviceCollection.AddScoped<HotelRepo>();`.

**2) Use it in tests:**   
`var HotelRepo = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HotelRepo>();
HotelRepo.CreateHotel(HotelInformation)`.